Where is VSCode Extension ID assigned - or how to assign it?
I am writing a VSCode extension and I would like to create custom context (right-click) menu options. I only want the custom context menu items to show up when the active tab is associated with (created by) my extension. I am trying to use contributes/menus in package.json with the following code:
  "contributes": {
    "menus": {
    "editor/context":
    [
      {
        "command": "qwget.qwget",
        "when": "extension == 'xxxx.xxxx'"
      }
    ]
  }
  }

where "xxxx.xxxx" will be the Extension ID.
I have referenced the "when clause contexts" at: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts
I know how to "find" the Extension ID for an existing extension in the marketplace. But I don't know how/when it is assigned.
Is the Extension ID supplied by the developer? If so, where would I find the naming conventions? Or, is it assigned when the extension is published to the marketplace? If it's the latter, then this seems somewhat like a "chicken/egg" situation. I need to specify the Extension ID in package.json, but I don't know what that is until I publish the extension...
Thanks in advance.


The id of an extension is always ${publisher}.${name}. For example:
vscode.csharp.

From Extension Manifest documentation - but it is non-obviously in the extensionDependencies or extensionPack entries.  It should have a heading entry of its own since the id is so frequently used.

Is this working for you?
